# Filter datatable by selectOneMenu's default value after page load

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I need the datatable to get filtered by the default value(see selectOneMenu 'chkNot', false in this case) **after page is loaded**.

*Current situation: The filter value get selected but the datatable doesn't get filtered. If I change the value then it works well.*

```
<ui:composition template="templates/layout.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:components="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >

  <ui:define name="title">Test Page</ui:define>
  <ui:define name="content">

        <h:form id="tranForm">
          <p:dataTable value="#{myBean.ordersAll}" var="order" 
                        id="myDTable" widgetVar="myDTable"
                        filteredValue="#{myBean.ordersAllFiltered}">

              <p:column filterBy="#{order.selected}" filterMatchMode="exact" headerText="Filter">
                  <f:facet name="filter">
                      <p:selectOneMenu id="chkNot" widgetVar="chkNot" 
                                        value="#{false}" 
                                        onchange="PF('myDTable').filter()" >
                      <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
                      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="#{true}" />
                      <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="#{false}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                  </f:facet>
                  <h:outputText value="#{order.selected}"/>
              </p:column>

          </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter function is triggered by PF('myDTable').filter() so you need to fire that event on page load. One way to do it is using javascript, for example like this:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" target="body">
$j = jQuery;
$j(document).ready( function() {
PF('myDTable').filter();   
});
</script>
```

**Update:**

Another way is to execute the filter function from the backing bean:

```
public void executeFilter() {
    RequestContext rc = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    rc.execute("PF('myDTable').filter();");
}
```

Comment: I've pasted your code just before the tranForm.Firefox says '`TypeError: PF(...) is undefined`', Chrome says '`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`'

Comment: That's because widgetVar="myDTable" has not been build in the DOM tree at the time you are calling the JS function. Move the script code below the form. Also since you intend to place it inside your body, you can remove the target="body"

Comment: If I change the selectOneMenu _chkNot_ `value="#{false}"` to `value="false"`, both approaches work. Otherwise it keeps giving `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Thanks!